# Reference request: almost sure weak convergence

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, almost-everywhere

I've encountered the term "almost sure weak convergence" of empirical measures in several places but haven't been able to find a textbook reference. Could anyone point me to a good reference? In particular, I am trying to understand the difference between "weak convergence" and "almost sure weak convergence".

Comment: Some related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926296/weak-convergence-of-measures-implying-almost-sure-convergence-of-random-variable https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420930/weak-convergence-to-almost-sure-convergence-in-the-skorokhod-theorem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622573/almost-sure-weak-convergence-of-empirical-measure -- the third seems to refer to a textbook

Comment: Thank you! I had seen those links but my confusion was the definition of a.s. weak convergence given in the third link is the same as the definition of weak convergence in, for example, Billingsley (1999) "Convergence of Probability Measures"